# Frama-c loop invariant

Tags: proof, frama-c

I just tried to prove a sort function in frama-c. However, when I proved the outer loop.

```
loop invariant 0 <= i <l;
loop invariant 0 < i < l ==> \forall int a,b; 0<=b <=l-i-1 <=a < l ==> 
t[a]>=t[b];
```

There is always with the orange bullets. I refer to many examples and I cannot find the reason. Is there someone that can help me? Thanks!!
The following is my source code:

```
/*@ predicate Swap{L1,L2}(int *a, integer l, integer i, integer j) =
 \at(a[i],L1) == \at(a[j],L2) &&
 \at(a[j],L1) == \at(a[i],L2) &&
 \forall integer k; k != i && k != j
     ==> \at(a[k],L1) == \at(a[k],L2);
 */


/*@ predicate Sorted{L}(int *a, integer l, integer h) =
 \forall integer i,j; l <= i <= j < h ==> a[i] <= a[j] ;
*/

/*@ requires \valid(t + (0..l-1));
requires 0 <= i < l;
requires 0 <= j < l;
assigns t[i],t[j];
ensures Swap{Old,Here}(t,l,i,j);
*/


void swap(int *t, int l, int i,int j){
int tmp;
tmp = t[i];
t[i] = t[j];
t[j] = tmp;
return;
}


 /*@ requires l >0;
requires \valid(t + (0..l-1));


ensures (\forall integer a; 0<=a <l
 ==> (\exists integer b; 0<= b < l
 ==> \at(t[b],Old)== \at(t[a],Here) ));
ensures Sorted{Here}(t, 0, l-1);
 */
void sort(int *t, int l) { 
int i;
int j;
i=j=0;

/*@ loop invariant 0 <= i <l;
loop invariant 0 < i < l ==> \forall int a,b; 0<=b <=l-i-1 <=a < l ==> 
t[a]>=t[b];
 */
for (i=0;i<l;i++) {


 /*@ 
loop invariant 0<= j < l; 
loop invariant 0 < j < l ==>\forall int a; 0<= a <= j ==> t[a]<=t[j];     
 */
for (j=0;j<l-1;j++) {

  if (t[j] > t[j+1]){ 

    swap(t,l ,j, j+1);}
    }
  }
}
```

and I use

```
frama-c-gui -wp sort.c
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code in detail, but as a very first step you should provide appropriate `loop assigns` in addition to your `loop invariant`. As a matter of fact, WP should have warned you about the issue (if you're on the GUI, be sure to always have a look at the `Warnings` tab to ensure that everything looks alright).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added     loop assigns j,t[j]; for the inner loop and 
    loop assigns i,j,t; for the outer loop. But for the outer loop it still cannot be proved...And there is a very strange result : when the first time I ran my modified codes the result is always better than after results....